# How can you fill in an open dialog box in headless chrome in Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, automation, headless

I'm working with Python and Selenium to do some automation in the office, and I need to fill in an "upload file" dialog box (a windows "open" dialog box), which was invoked from a site using a headless chrome browser. Does anyone have any idea on how this could be done?

If I wasn't using a headless browser, Pywinauto could be used with a line similar to the following, for example, but this doesn't appear to be an option in headless chrome:

app.pane.open.ComboBox.Edit.type_keys(uploadfilename + "{ENTER}")

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to not be possible. I ended up running the code on a VM and setting a registry key to allow automation to be run while the VM was minimized, disconnected, or otherwise not being interacted with by users.